# error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly for SQLEXPRESS 2012

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, serve

i have installed SQLEXPRESS 2012 on my computuer (WINDOWS SERVER 2008) which i have already installed SQL SERVER 2008 and it work perfectly.
When i try to start SQLEXPRESS service i get this error message "error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly".

I'm using a system which having credentials managed by an active directory server.

Comment: The 2x instances must be falling out over something. I suggest you start by checking the ports setup for the TCP protocols for the 2x named express instances. Are they both dynamic? This can be done in the SQL Config Mgr. Also is the SQL Browser Service running?

Answer (score 0):

I am writing it right now for someone who can meet such error in future.
I had the same error, and the reason was incorrect paths in register. My actual instance of sql server is situated in D:\Program Files... But all of those paths leaded to C:\Program Files... I am not sure about the reason of such renaming, but that occurred after windows update...

So, If you get this error, find your sql instance in register and check all the paths in variables.

My instance's path is
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS

Hope that will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Run services.msc
Right click SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) service, select Proprerties
Select tab Log On, checked Local System account > OK
Start SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) service